# Listening and passing data without stopping

Tags: java, multithreading

This code illustrates my problem:

```
//Constructor
public ReadFormat(String path, int nic) throws IOException{
     this.path = path;
     this.nic = String.valueOf(nic);        
    ReadTshark();    //Calls listening function
}

//listening stdout and sends to another
public void ReadTshark() throws IOException{
    String cmdTshark = path + " -S" + " -i "+ nic + " -R "+ "\"udp.port == 9000\" " + "-E header=y -E separator=, -Tfields -e frame.len -e frame.time_delta";  
    System.out.println(cmdTshark);
    String s=null;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdTshark);
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        // read the output from the command
    int i=0;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null && b) {
            System.out.println(s);
            rawin[i]=s;
            if(i==100){
                Separate();    //When rawin reaches 100, sends to another function to process    
            }
        }
}

//receives data and sends to another function
private void Separate(){
}
//receives data and sends to another function
private void NextFunction{
}
```

How can I pass the data function to function without:

1. Stop listening until otherwise;
2. Continue to pass data on to functions, so as soon the data is sent the function will be able to receive more.

Just like a chain, send and ready to receive immediately!

Comment: Sounds like the sort of thing queues were made for, no?

Comment: Don't know, never heard about it. I will search. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to move stream data between threads, you should look at the `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` classes.  your `ReadTshark()` would write the data it reads to the PipedOutputStream, and your other thread would read the data from a linked PipedInputStream.

of course, i see no reason why your other thread would not just use the `p.getInputStream()` directly.

Comment: Because the data will suffer changes and calculations, and the next function will receive that same changes. Since the output is very faste and calculations are computer intensive, i must have a method that dont stop the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't answer your specific question, have you considered using a Java packet capture library rather than trying to capture the output from a forked TShark?

I find [JNetPCap](http://jnetpcap.com/) quite easy to use.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.